# Sublinhar uma palavra dentro de um TextView

Tags: java, android, android-xml

Como posso sublinhar, deixar em negrito/itálico uma única palavra dentro de uma `TextView`?

por exemplo:

```
  <TextView
            android:text="Abelha Barco Casa Dado"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:id="@+id/textView

            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
```

"Abelha **Barco** Casa Dado"

devo utilizar algum codigo html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem algumas opções que você pode aderir para um [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html), no qual vou dar alguns exemplos.

### [SpannableStringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html)

Esta é a classe cujo conteúdo e marcação podem ambos ser alterados, considerando ser uma abordagem mais nativa.

```
SpannableStringBuilder texto = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        texto.append("Jeitos de colocar ");
        int start = texto.length();
        texto.append("o texto negrito");
        texto.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), start, 
        texto.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        texto.append(" em um TextView");

        textView.setText(texto);
```

### [Html.fromHtml](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html)

Usar algumas das *tags* HTML para formatar texto usado em um `TextView`.

```
String texto = "Jeitos de colocar <b>o texto negrito</b> em um TextView";

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
   textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(texto,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
} else {
   textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(texto));
}
```

**Parâmetros:**

```
public static final int FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT = 63;
public static final int FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY = 0;
public static final int FROM_HTML_OPTION_USE_CSS_COLORS = 256;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_BLOCKQUOTE = 32;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_DIV = 16;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_HEADING = 2;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_LIST = 8;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_LIST_ITEM = 4;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_PARAGRAPH = 1;
public static final int TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_CONSECUTIVE = 0;
public static final int TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_INDIVIDUAL = 1;
```

### [String Resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html?hl=pt-br)

Os recursos de *string* fornecem *strings* de texto para o aplicativo com estilo e formatação de texto opcional.

**string.xml**

```
<resources>
    ...
    ...
    <string name="TextoHtml"> 
     Jeitos de colocar 
     <b>o texto negrito</b> 
     em um TextView
    </string>
</resources>
```

**main.java**

```
textView.setText(getString(R.string.TextoHtml));
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o método [`Html.fromHtml`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) -> **`Spanned fromHtml (String source)`**

```
Spanned text = Html.fromHtml("Abelha <b>Barco</b> Casa Dado");
textView.setText(text);
```

---

### Este método está obsoleto a partir da `API Level 24`, portanto, você deverá implementar algo parecido como:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24)
{
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Abelha <b>Barco</b> Casa Dado",Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));    
}
else
{
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Abelha <b>Barco</b> Casa Dado"));
}
```

> [FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)